# Add tooltip to postscript image using pdfmark ann

Tags: pdfmark

How can I add a mouse over 'tooltip' to a postscript image using pdfmark annotation please?

I'm compiling a large PDF from several hundred postscript images and have a Perl script to automatically add hyperlinks to each postscript image to aid navigation (these are then referenced in a LaTeX document using [\includegraphics](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx)).  I'm using the pdfmark code like the following for the hyperlink, but what would the tooltip code associated with this link look like please:

```
[ /Rect [ 1294 1037 1799 2837 ]
/Dest /pi_target_child
/Border [0 0 2]
/Color [.7 0 0]
/Subtype /Link
/ANN pdfmark
```

I've had a look through the [pdfmark documentation](http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/acrobat/sdk/pdf/pdf_creation_apis_and_specs/pdfmarkReference.pdf) but unable to work out if this is possible.  I've tried adding /Title (my tooltip text) to the above but without success.

==Edit==

I've discovered the widget subtype and can add a tooltip to the image, but unfortunately this has broken the hyperlink.  The mouse cursor changes (correctly) to a hand, from arrow, when hovering over the hyperlink section but left clicking does not navigate away...  Almost there!?

```
[ /Subtype /Widget
/Rect [ 1294 1037 1799 2837 ]
/F 4
/TU (My tooltip)
/T (tooltip \thetooltip)
/FT /Btn
/DA (/Helv 0 Tf 0 0 1 rg)
/Ff 65536
/ANN pdfmark
```

Comment: Ah..., I think I got the point. Replace `/Dest /pi_target_child` with `/A<</S/GoTo/D/pi_target_child>>` in the `/Widget` annotation. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `/Link` annotations don't display tooltips, `/Widget` annotations must be used. However, the Destination specification in `/Widget` annotations is different from `/Link` annotations. The destination must be embedded into an action dictionary of type `/GoTo`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,hyperref,filecontents}

%%%%%% postscript file with embedded Widget annotations %%%%%%
\begin{filecontents*}{cross.ps}
%!PS-Adobe-1.0
%%BoundingBox: 0 0 100 100

0 0 moveto 50 50 rlineto stroke
0 50 moveto 50 -50 rlineto stroke

[ /Subtype /Widget
/Rect [0 0 50 50]
/F 4
/TU (Lower left)  %used as tooltip text
/T (Lower left)   %unique Widget name
/FT /Btn 
/Ff 65536
/A <</S/GoTo /D/llcross>>
/ANN pdfmark

50 50 moveto 50 50 rlineto stroke
50 100 moveto 50 -50 rlineto stroke

[ /Subtype /Widget
/Rect [50 50 100 100]
/F 4
/TU (Upper right)
/T (Upper right)
/FT /Btn
/Ff 65536
/A <</S/GoTo /D/urcross>>
/ANN pdfmark
\end{filecontents*}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
\includegraphics{cross}
\newpage
\hypertarget{llcross}{You clicked the lower left cross.}
\newpage
\hypertarget{urcross}{You clicked the upper right cross.}
\end{document}
```

Make sure, that all `Widget` annotation names are unique (`/T (unique name)`).

Answer (score 3):

here is an example for two tooltips, marked as ?. Instead of plotting the axes you can use `\rput[lt](0,0){\includegraphics{..}}` or without `\rput`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcounter{tooltip}
\newcommand\tooltip[2]{%
% arg #1: text to put on the page
% arg #2: tooltip text
  \pdfmark[#1]{
    pdfmark=/ANN,
    Subtype=/Widget,
    Raw={
      /TU (#2)/T (tooltip \thetooltip)
      /FT/Btn/Ff 65536/H/N
    }
  }%
  \stepcounter{tooltip}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{pspicture}(-4,-4)(4,4)
  \psaxes{->}(0,0)(-4,-4)(4,4)
  \rput[c](0,0){\tooltip{\color{red}?}{Origin}}
  \rput[c](4,4){\tooltip{\color{red}?}{top right}}
  \rput[c](-4,-4){\tooltip{\color{red}?}{bottom left}}
\end{pspicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

needs `latex->dvips->ps2pdf`

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer and providing a MWE.  I really want to address this directly in the postscript code.  My images are large and I'm adding several hyperlinks targets over the top of each one.  I've tried previously to achieve this in TeX but found directly adding them in ps much easier.  Just need to find a way of adding the tooltps there too :)  Thanks again.  Appreciated.

Comment: create only one tooltip and have a look into the ps file. Should be easy to understand what was done.

Comment: Yes I looked but didn't see any link annotations, just widget.  Issue I have now is getting the two working together..  Started to look a /Action /Subtype